# How do I stop text scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ticker() {
        $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function() {
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown();
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 3000);
});
```

I don't know how to stop the text scrolling when I place the mouse over a particular title.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/h2zxuyk3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover) to clear the interval and when mouse leaves then again start the ticker like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ticker() {
        $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function () {
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown();
        });
    }

    var clr = null;
    function animate(){
        clr=setInterval(function () {
            ticker();
        }, 3000);
    }
    animate();
    $('#ticker li').hover(function () {
        // clear interval when mouse enters
        clearInterval(clr);
    },function(){
        // again start animation when mouse leaves
        animate();
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/h2zxuyk3/1/)

Comment: Thank You so much sir @rohan kumar

Answer (score 1):

Minor update in your answer. Use mouseover and out function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function ticker() {
     $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown();
     });
  }

var ticke = setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 3000);
    $('#ticker li').mouseover(function() { 
          clearInterval(ticke);
      }).mouseout(function() { 
          ticke= setInterval(function(){ ticker(); }, 3000);
    });
 });
```

[See here Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h2zxuyk3/2/)

Comment: Thank You so much sir @sehta umesh

Answer (score 1):

please try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ticker() {
        $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(function () {
            $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown();
        });
    }

    var clr = null;
    function animate(){
        clr=setInterval(function () {
            ticker();
        }, 3000);
    }
    animate();
    $('#ticker li').hover(function () {
        // clear interval when mouse enters
        clearInterval(clr);
    },function(){
        // again start animation when mouse leaves
        animate();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) method returns an `id` value which you can then pass to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) to cancel the calls to `ticker()`.